# How to append jQuery events to new elements?

Tags: jquery, events, svg

I have a SVG canvas and when I double-click on it, I create a new SVG element inside it.

How I do to create a click event for these new elements created at real time by the id of the new element.

These elements ids will be a word I inform.

The elements are created by an external API (Graph Dracula), so can't change it.

Example: I add a new element called "Renato", so the element id will be "Renato".

Comment: If those SVG elements share a common click handler, consider event delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should just be able to bind it using something like:

$("#...").click(function() { ... });

Basically it's like normal.  You just need some kind of reference to it and you can use jQuery to bind something on it.  If you're creating it, you obviously have a reference to it then, so you could do it at that step.

Edit: just read that they're created by an external API.  However, if you know the id, you can always just use $("#idhere").

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use the live function in jQuery. It can tie events to dynamically created elements after the DOM has loaded.

```
$("#Renato").live("click", function(){...});
```

Or in later versions of jQuery

```
$('#some_non_dynamic_parent').on('click', '#Renato', function(){});
```